# asp.net link button not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a link button inside the asp.net repeater control. I am trying to call the serverside method on the click event but no luck. I tried html anchor but it is not working so I switched to link button.

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <li class="showmenu">
   <p class="subtext">&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="frontimagechange_click">Front</asp:LinkButton></p>
  <a href="#"><img id="Img1" src='<%# this.ResolveUrl("~/testimages/" + Eval("front")) %>' width="350" height="560" alt='<%# Eval("stylenumber") %>' runat="server" align="left" /></a>                             
 </li>                   
</ItemTemplate>
```

server-side code:

```
protected void frontimagechange_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//code to get the id of link button and change the 
//src of the image control inside the repeater
}
```

Comment: @rahul for most of the questions i havent got the answer and i tried some other ways to solve the issue.

Comment: are you sure you didnt get the answer .actually i checked your questions and all of them at least one or two answers except that grid one outofindex error

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle `ItemCommand` event of [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) control.

Data controls such as the Repeater, DataList, GridView, FormView, and DetailsView controls uses [Forwarded events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx).

> Summary:
>
> Rather than each button raising an event individually, events from the
>   nested controls are forwarded to the container control. The container
>   in turn raises a generic ItemCommand event with parameters that allow
>   you to discover which individual control raised the original event. By
>   responding to this single event, you can avoid having to write
>   individual event handlers for child controls.

Demo:

Markup (.aspx)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton 
            ID="LinkButton1" 
            runat="server"
            CommandName="cmd"
            >Click Me</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In code-behind file,

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmd")
    {
        LinkButton button = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get the linkbutton's id or something unique to change the image control's src. How to achieve this with ItemCommand

Comment: @sam on the linkbutton, set CommandName and CommandArgument. Within the ItemCommand handler, catch and look for the CommandArgument value. The documentation link should explain more.

Comment: @Blake the problem is if the linkbutton is fired then i could catch the CommandArgument. but it is not firing at all.

Comment: javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$list$ctl01$frontlink&#39;,&#39;&#39;) linkbutton's href

Comment: @sam as the other answer mentions, is autoEventwireup="true", is viewstate enabled. Do you have any other events firing on the page that are working?

Answer (score 1):

is autoEventWireUp = true in your page ?

did yo u enable viewstate for the repeater or page.

it will not work if the viewstate is off